# Leave A Comment With Json Wordpress in Xcode

Tags: ios, json, swift, wordpress, xcode

i made app with Xcode in swift using my Wordpress backend and getting data with json, i can show users comment on my app but i want that users can also leave comments in the app, there should be an option for Leave a comment on post details file, this is my code for showing comments

```
 @IBAction func commentViewController(_ sender: Any) {
        let vc = CommentViewController()
        vc.dataArray = jsonData["comments"].array
        self.navigationController!.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
    }

 self.commentButton.layer.borderWidth = 2
        self.commentButton.layer.borderColor = baseColor.cgColor
        self.commentButton.layer.cornerRadius = 4.0
        self.commentButton.tintColor = baseColor
        self.commentButton.setTitle("comments(\(jsonData["comments"].array?.count ?? 0))", for: .normal)
```

but i don't know how to make a comment box where users can also leave comment , thanks

This Is My CommentViewController:

```
 var tableView: UITableView  =   UITableView()
var dataArray: Array<JSON>!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.title = "Comments"

    if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
        navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
        navigationController?.navigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode = .automatic

        let attributes = [
            NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor : navigationBarTextColor, NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont(name: "SFUIText-Medium", size: 34),
            ]

        navigationController?.navigationBar.largeTitleTextAttributes = attributes as [NSAttributedString.Key : Any]

    } else {
        // Fallback on earlier versions
    }

    // Check if Post have comments
    if(self.dataArray.count == 0){
        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 216 / 255, green: 216 / 255, blue: 216 / 255, alpha: 1.0)
        let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: (UIScreen.main.bounds.width/2)-100, y: (UIScreen.main.bounds.height/2)-50, width: 200, height: 50))
        label.text = "No Comments"
        label.font = UIFont(name: "SFUIText-Regular", size: 18)
        label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.center
        self.view.addSubview(label)
    }
    else{
       self.setupTable()
    }
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


func getDateFromString(String:String) -> String{
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
    let dateObj = dateFormatter.date(from: String)
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
    return dateFormatter.string(from: dateObj!)
}


func setupTable(){
    tableView = UITableView(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds, style: UITableView.Style.plain)
    tableView.delegate      =   self
    tableView.dataSource    =   self
    tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "commentViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
    tableView.frame.size.height = UIScreen.main.bounds.height - 64
    tableView.bounces = false
    tableView.allowsSelection = false
    self.view.addSubview(self.tableView)
}

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
{
  return self.dataArray.count
 }

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! commentViewCell
    cell.commentText.text = String(htmlEncodedString: dataArray[indexPath.row]["content"].stringValue)
    cell.name.text = String(htmlEncodedString:dataArray[indexPath.row]["name"].stringValue)
    cell.date.text = getDateFromString(String: dataArray[indexPath.row]["date"].stringValue)

    return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return UITableView.automaticDimension
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return UITableView.automaticDimension
}
```

}

Comment: You need a UITextField or UITextView if this is really what you are asking about, the question is rather vague.

Comment: How does your CommentViewController look like?

Comment: i have edited the question please review @OlhaPavliuk

Answer (score 0):

So you have a "tableView" field where all comments are shown.
As `Joakim Danielson` advices, you should add UITextView to the bottom of your screen.

Because the table view can be too long to fit the screen height, it probably will be scrolled, so it's easier to add this text view as a cell.

So you can do this in a following way:

1. Change the size of tableView for leaving the comment at the end:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
{
  return self.dataArray.count + 1
}
```

2. Add the cell with text view, let's name it `LeaveCommentCell`
   [image]
3. Return the `LeaveCommentCell` instance as the last cell:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    if indexPath.row == self.dataArray.count  { // this is the last row
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "AddCommentCell", for: indexPath) as! LeaveCommentCell // your new cell

        return cell
    }
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ShowCommentCell", for: indexPath) as! commentViewCell // please note identifiers should differ 
    cell.commentText.text = String(htmlEncodedString: dataArray[indexPath.row]["content"].stringValue)
    cell.name.text = String(htmlEncodedString:dataArray[indexPath.row]["name"].stringValue)
    cell.date.text = getDateFromString(String: dataArray[indexPath.row]["date"].stringValue)

    return cell
}
```

4. Add a button (e.g. with text "Post") to `LeaveCommentCell`, subscribe for event when it's pressed, get comment text and send it to server.